# If $4ax+3by+12c$ is normal to ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, then how are $c$, $a$, $e$ related?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Here we have equation of normal of ellipse, $4ax+3by=12c$
> and ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$
>
> What is the relation between $(c, a, e)$?
>
> (a) $c=a^2e^2\quad$ (b) $c=5a^2e^2\quad$ (c) $5c=a^2e^2\quad$ (d) None of these
>
> The answer is (c) $5c=a^2e^2$.

I tried to solved it with formula of normal and by putting normal points in it. ($ae,\pm\dfrac{b^2}{e}$), so here $\dfrac{a^2x}{x_1}+\dfrac{b^2y}{y_1}=a^2-b^2$, but couldn't find the relation.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community i have added exact picture of questions clarified

Comment: Hint : Write the normal equation to the curve and compare it with the  equation of normal in question.

Comment: @An_Elephant can you not see what I wrote above? I have already wrote the equation and compare it but what should I do for x1,y1 should I point normal point on it which is ae b^2/a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my try

The condition for a line $Ax+By+C=0$ to be normal to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is

> $$\frac{a^2}{A^2}+\frac{b^2}{B^2}=\frac{(a^2-b^2)^2}{C^2}$$

Now, your line is $4ax+3by-12c=0$ and ellipse is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, on comparing we get,

1. $A=4a$
2. $B=3b$
3. $C=-12c$

Also using the fact that $b^2=a^2(1-e^2)$ to get $a^2-b^2=a^2e^2$;

$$\frac{a^2}{16a^2}+\frac{b^2}{9b^2}=\frac{(a^2e^2)^2}{144c^2}$$

> $$5c=a^2e^2$$

So option (c) is correct.

Extra- the parametric coordinates of an ellipse of the form $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ are $(acos\theta,bsin\theta)$ and the equation of normal to the ellipse in parametric form is $\frac{ax}{cos\theta}+\frac{by}{sin\theta}=a^2-b^2$. Compare this normal equation with Ax+By+C=0, we get $sin\theta=\frac{bC}{B(a^2-b^2)}$ and $cos\theta=\frac{aC}{A(a^2-b^2)}$. Now use the usual identity $sin^2\theta+cos^2\theta=1$ to get to the condition mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you so much. Parametric solution is also fascinating